# F# project compiling error for a function returning a tuple

Tags: f#, return, tuples

I created an F# project by visual studio, added function like this:

```
let fangle a b c =
  a+1, b+1, c+1

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
printfn "%i,%i,%i" (fangle 3 4 5) // compile error
```

### There's compiling error at the call of (fangle 3 4 5), it says:

```
Error 2 The type '(int * int * int)' is not compatible with any of the types
byte,int16,int32,int64,sbyte,uint16,uint32,uint64,nativeint,unativeint,
arising from the use of a printf-style format string 
C:\Users\mis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication3\Program.fs 20 25 ConsoleApplication3
```

Why such an error, in my function definition?

Answer (score 7):

it's not your function definition - it's the way you use `printfn` (the F# compiler is indeed checking if you use the right parameters for the given format-string).

So by doing

```
printfn "%i,%i,%i" (fangle 3 4 5)
```

you are telling F# to *print* three integers (separated by ',') - you can think of it's type to be `printf "%i,%i,%i" : int -> int -> int -> unit` - but you give it a tuple `int*int*int` (namely the result of evaluating `fangle` for `a=3, b=4, c=5`) so now F# is trying to figure out how to match the first curried type `int` from `printf "%i,%i,%i"` with the type `int*int*int` and I just cannot - therefore the error.

The obvious fix would be:

```
printfn "%A" (fangle 3 4 5)
```

where you tell F# to format the resulting tuple:

```
> printfn "%A" (fangle 3 4 5);;
(4, 5, 6)
val it : unit = ()
```

or you can first deconstruct the tuple:

```
> let (x,y,z) = fangle 3 4 5 in printfn "%i,%i,%i" x y z;;
4,5,6
val it : unit = ()
```

or you can go ballistic/fancy ;)

```
let uncurry3 f (x,y,z) = f x y z

> uncurry3 (printfn "%i,%i,%i") (fangle 3 4 5);;
4,5,6
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this statement separately without assigning to (x,y,z)

Comment: fangle 3 4 5 in printfn "%i,%i,%i" x y z;;

Comment: But this statement fails inside fsi ,reporting:   fangle 3 4 5 in printfn "%i,%i,%i" x y z;;
  -------------^^

stdin(11,14): error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'in' in interaction. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point, ';', ';;' or other token.

Comment: the `let` here is important - it's an expression (anywhere in F# not only F# interactive) : `let v = blah in whatever`

Answer (score 7):

Additionally to what Carsten already said in his answer, you can also use the [pipe-operator |||>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370269.aspx) to deconstruct the tuple while passing them as arguments to another function:

```
let fangle a b c =
    a+1, b+1, c+1

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    fangle 3 4 5
    |||> printfn "%i,%i,%i"
```

Comment: yeah - I tend to forget those :D (stupid SO-fascism will not even let me +1 your good answer with a comment ... but hey it's easy to defeat the filters)